# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm having this issue: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined on my discord bot after adding aliases. It worked before I added aliases to it so I'm assuming the problem is somewhere around there. I can't seem to find where the problem is originating from so any help would be appreciated!

**code:**

```
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
let profile = require("./profiles.json");

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

    if(err) console.log(err);

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
    if(jsfile.length <= 0){
        console.log("Couldn't find commands");
        return;
    };

    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        console.log(`${f} loaded!`);
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
        props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            bot.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
        });
    });
});



bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online`);
    bot.user.setActivity("$ Made by xkillerx15");
});

bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot,message,args);

    if(!profile[message.author.id]){
        profile[message.author.id] = {
            coins: 0
        };
    }

    let coinAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    let baseAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    if(coinAmt === baseAmt){
        profile[message.author.id] = {
            coins: profile[message.author.id].coins + coinAmt
        };
        fs.writeFile("./profiles.json", JSON.stringify(profile), (err) => {
            if(err) console.log(err)
        });
    }
});

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

**exact error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at jsfile.forEach (C:\Users\Jordy\Desktop\jbot\index.js:23:28)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at fs.readdir (C:\Users\Jordy\Desktop\jbot\index.js:19:12)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
```

Comment: You haven't defined aliases for at least one command. If you want to stick with this code, you *must* declare aliases as an array in each command (for no aliases, keep it blank). If you don't want to bother with changing all your command files, define an `aliases` variable as `props.help.aliases || []`, which will use an empty array if `props.help.aliases` isn't defined, and iterate over that instead.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `aliases` is `undefined` which means is not an object so you can't use `forEach`

there is one possibility:

1. commands file should contains  `aliases` inside `help` object.
   so it should something like this

   ```
   exports.help = {
   aliases:[...props]
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem with that is that "commands" is a folder, not a file. If I add aliases: "somealias"; to each file it won't work either. I've watched a youtube video on aliases and I did exactly the same as the youtuber did but for some reason my file still gives errors

Comment: did you try to declare aliases as an array?
because this is what your code says 
`jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {` we will go through every js file 
`        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);` and we will import matched file 
`props.help.aliases` here props should be an object and should contain a property called help and it should be an object contains a proprity called aliases and it should be an array